# Regex match Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to notify a user of invalid characters entered into an input using `RegularExpressions`, however, it always returns `null`.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var nome = $('#name');
  var regex = /^[a-zA-Z ]{3,50}$/;
  var btn = $('#btnGo');

  btn.on('click', function() {
    if (!regex.test(nome.val()))
      alert(nome.val().match(regex).join(''));
    else
      alert('Ok');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="btnGo">Go</button>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If `regex.test()` returns false, then of course `match()` is going to return null. It means there is no match.

Comment: You are right...:) but how can notify the invalid char to user?

Comment: use your regex to look for invalid chars instead. `var regex = /^[^a-zA-Z ].*$/;` if that is true you can use `match` to get the wrong chars.

Comment: Your regex is checking if the entry is valid. So, write a regex that searches for *invalid* characters.

Comment: @wayneOS: Almost, except leave out the `^` and `$` markers: `var regex = /[^a-zA-Z ].*/g;` Otherwise, it will only match strings that consist entirely of invalid characters. Also, add `g` at the end so that it finds all matches.

Comment: tks  Máté Safranka ... it works. Im using regex without understand the match method :). bye and tks

Comment: @MátéSafranka omg, yes you are right! wrote that in a hurry. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second regex similar to the current one and test that. `/[^a-zA-Z ]/g` will match all items that is the opposite of the original regex sinc the first item within `[]` is a `^`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var nome = $('#name');
  var acceptable = 'a-zA-Z.\', ';
  var valid = new RegExp(`^[${acceptable}]{3,50}$`);
  var invalid = new RegExp(`[^${acceptable}]`, 'g');
  var btn = $('#btnGo');

  btn.on('click', function() {
    if (!valid.test(nome.val()))
      alert(nome.val().match(invalid).join(''));
    else
      alert('Ok');
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="name" />
<button id="btnGo">Go</button>
```

Comment: Nice ...just want to include  dot apostrophe and comma...how place in the valid regex?

Comment: You just need to add them to the list of items.

Comment: I have made an update, have a look, you just need to change the `acceptable` variable with items you want to accept.

Comment: Very readable ...more mantainable..tks. Im a newbie with js jquery